# Disable Topshelf console output

Tags: c#, console, output, topshelf

When calling `HostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem()` or equivalent, the TopShelf library outputs several lines to the console.

How to I prevent TopShelf from outputing these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console output is logging information.  If you use a logging framework with Topshelf the lines appear in log files instead of the console.

I recommend using a logging framework with Topshelf. You should always be logging in a serious project anyway, and it eliminates the lines from the console. Win/win.

Comment: You could also implement a `NullLogger`, https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/develop/src/Topshelf/Logging/LogWriter.cs is the interface you need to implement and register if I recall correctly.

Comment: That's another option. For my own edification, how would I register the `NullLogger`?

Comment: `HostLogger.UseLogger()` is what you use to register it. It's in the Topshelf.Logging namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst William Morrison's answer is correct, for the benefit of people landing here looking to enable logging with TopShelf, here is one of the ways using NLog

Step 1: Install the following via NuGet
PackageManager Console> Install-Package TopShelf
PackageManager Console> Install-Package TopShelf.NLog

Step 2: In the configuration lambda, tell TopShelf that you intend to use NLog

```
HostFactory.Run(configurator =>
            {
                configurator.Service<NotificationEngineService>(svc =>
                {
                    // configure service start, stop etc. here
                });

                // The below option is add via TopShelf.NLog.dll assembly
                configurator.UseNLog();
                // Continue configuring

            });
```

Comment: Good thinking posting an example. Thanks!